# Passing parameters to a flash movie inserted in a VB program

Tags: vb.net, flash

I need to insert a Flash movie in a Visual Basic 2008 express form and send parameters to the movie, but am a newbie to VB. The flash movie will plot points sent by VB in a graph.

I tried to insert the Shockwave Flash control in the form but cannot find it anywhere. So I inserted the webbrowser control, which I understand can be used to a similar purpose. But how would I send the values of X and Y (coordinates to plot in Flash) to the flash swf?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

So I think it's better that you import the Shockwave flash Activex in your project. I'm not familiar with VB IDE but all the thing you need to do is that importing the Shockwave Falsh Ocx after that you can access to the all of the initiative parameters which you need.